# asp.net control querystring

Tags: asp.net, controls, query-string

I have a label control in an aspx page, can i set value to the label from an handler file? How can i pass the reference of the label through query string?

Comment: Could you add more details?  You have a custom ASHX, or a handler implementing IHandler?  How is this handler being invoked in reference to the page?

Comment: Ya. i have a file with name 'SalesOrderStatus.ashx' and inside this i have the class                                               public class SalesOrderStatus : IHttpHandler
    {

Answer (score 1):

From the main page:

```
string URL = "www.whatever.com/test.ashx?lblText=" + lbl_MyLable.Text;
```

Comment: then, if i have set "Hai" from handler file.., How can i do it.

Comment: I have a label in abc.aspx, say 'label1'. I want to assign a value to 'label1' from another page xyz.ashx. How can i do this?

Comment: Not sure you could.  Maybe using PostBackURL but i'm not sure.  The question is why would you want to?